# When one class uses another and vice-versa in Python

Tags: python, class

Suppose I have a class named `Point`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
    ...
```

Also I have a class named `Line` which uses `Point` inside:

```
class Line:
    #tail and head are supposed to be Point objects
    def __init__(self, tail, head):
        self.__tail = tail
        self.__head = head
```

The problem is I want `Point` to have `reflect` method which is just reflects point with respect to `Line line`:

```
#Point class
def reflect(self, line):
    #Reflection code that uses Line methods
```

So I have cross-reference here. The question is what is the best way to solve this? Or should I avoid such approach?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you.mean by cross reference?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you are using double-underscores for your attribute names?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. I have add comment that `line` is `Line` object and `tail` and `head` are the `Point` objects.

Comment: By "cross reference", do you mean cyclic imports?

Comment: Yes, I assumed so. I still don't understand your question. What is a cross reference, and why is it a problem?

Comment: I mean that class `Line` uses `Point` and vice-versa.

Comment: @paraxod And how is that a problem?

Comment: What makes you think it could be a problem?

Comment: `reflect` should probably be a non-member function. It doesn't seem a natural property or behaviour of a `Point`. You don't want it to be a dumping ground for all your transformations. (hint - maybe create a `Transformer` object)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your replies. Secondly, I have changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no cross referencing, no cycles, no infinite loops, and no infinite recursion, all is clear. You can do like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def reflect(self, line):  # line is a Line object
        reflected_x = None # replace w code to calc the reflection of x  vs. line
        reflected_y = None # replace w code to calc the reflection of y  vs. line
        return Point(reflected_x, reflected_y)

class Line:   # a Line defined by two Points 
    def __init__(self, tail, head):
        self.tail = tail
        self.head = head
```

I removed the double underscore in your variables, there were no reasons to have it in the first place.

#### Alternatively:

> (following Peter Wood advice in the comments):   reflect should
>   probably be a non-member function. It doesn't seem a natural property
>   or behaviour of a Point. You don't want it to be a dumping ground for
>   all your transformations. (hint - maybe create a Transformer object)

Or a simple function, taking a Line and a Point as arguments:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Line:   # a Line defined by two Points 
    def __init__(self, tail, head):
        self.tail = tail
        self.head = head


def reflect(line, point):  # line is a Line object
    reflected_x = None # replace w code to calc the reflection of point.x  vs. line
    reflected_y = None # replace w code to calc the reflection of point.y  vs. line
    return Point(reflected_x, reflected_y)
```